# Конфликт между jquery ui sortable и jquery custom content scroller

Tags: jquery-ui, прокрутка

Я столкнулся с проблемой использования jquery custom content scroller в паре с jquery ui sortable. У меня есть список с перетаскиваемыми элементами, которые можно двигать или удалять, после чего они выстраиваются заново из оставшихся элементов. Моя задача была повесить на этот список кастомный скролл, так как список может содержать большое количество элементов.

При загрузке страницы все в порядке. Проблемы начинаются, когда пытаешься сдвинуть один из элементов списка (`<li>`). Происходит какая-то несостыковка между библиотеками, после чего кастомный скролл пропадает, появляется дефолтный скролбар, а сам список получает дополнительную ширину и уходит в футер, так как ломается лэйаут.

Также я заметил, что при попытке перетащить один из элементов списка меняется структура ДОМ-дерева относящего к скроллу. `div.mCustomScrollBox` становится соседним элементом для всех элементов списка, вместо того чтобы быть их родителем.

**До**

```
<ul class="subjectsMenu mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1 mCS-dir-rtl">
<div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" tabindex="0">
    <div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container ui-sortable" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="rtl">
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
        <li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

**После**

```
<ul class="subjectsMenu mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1 mCS-dir-rtl mCS_no_scrollbar"><div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" tabindex="0">
<div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container ui-sortable mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="rtl"></div>
    <div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-light mCSB_scrollTools_vertical" style="display: none;">
        <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
            <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 40px; display: block; height: 335px; max-height: 740px; top: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 40px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
<li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
<li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
<li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
<li class="ui-sortable-handle">...</li>
```

Comment: В `ul` может быть только `li`. выносите `.mCustomScrollBox` и `.mCSB_container` за пределы `ul`

Comment: Я их расположением не управляю, они сами в него добавляются из jquery custom content scroller библиотеки. Это по сути дивы относящиеся к кастомному скроллу.

Comment: значит нужно обернуть в `div` список и в плагине `jquery custom content scroller ` в виде селектора вызывать не `ul`, а `div`.

Comment: Да, у меня идея была такая же. Это единственное к чему я пришел. Но это настолько здоровенная система, и там столько динамически создаваемых объектов, что скорее всего из-за смены структуры HTML все пойдет крахом. Попробовать я пожалуй все таки рискну, но скорее всего это потянет за собой ряд проблем. В любом случае, благодарю за дельный совет!